# Appointment.Save and Appointment.Update always set IsMeeting to true

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exchangewebservices

I want to create appointments, not meetings:

```
Appointment app = new Appointment(ews);
app.Start = DateTime.Now;
app.End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
app.Subject = "My Subject";
app.Save();
string unid = app.Id.UniqueId;
// here the unid is given to the client, that may make another call leading to:
ItemId iid = new ItemId(unid);
app = Appointment.Bind(ews, iid, calendarFullEntryProperties);
return app.IsMeeting; // Will return true, although I never added any participants.
```

Why is that? Did I overlook anything in the docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EWS uses the same object type for meetings and appointments. The default behavior when you `Save()` or `Update()` an appointment is to send meeting invitations even if you haven't invited anyone. This essentially sets the **IsMeeting** to *true*. To save this as an appointment, change your line of code for saving to this:

```
app.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
```

This will keep invitations from being sent and keep **IsMeeting** set to *false*.

Comment: Good to know, thx. Is this behaviour already part of the documentation?

Comment: I don't think it's documented to this detail so I'm putting in a request to make sure it gets covered properly.

Comment: Is there any way to get around this limitation and send the invitation anyway? Maybe by creating a meeting invitation programmatically?